# Remove index.php in magento url

Tags: magento-1.9

Getting Default error on removing `index.php from url`.
i did same but getting error now.
2.In `System -> Configuration -> Web -> Search Engines Optimizations- > Use Web Server Rewrites ->select YES`

Second thing index.php is case sensitive, some times my website url automatically convert to capital letters like (http://www.blumelife.co/Index.php/about-us/) this url is working very well. but some time it changes automatically to (http://www.blumelife.co/index.php/about-us/) so it shows default error.
How can i stop this case sensitivty.

I installed magento 1.9 and server is window server.

Comment: what is your redirect url settings in .htaccess file ?

Comment: Thanks Siddharth for reply. .htaccess setting is default if you want i can show u. but one thing to ask .htaccess is working on window server ?

Comment: are you using XAMPP or apache ?

Comment: No i am using 1&1 Hosting (Window)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make incase sensitive with with apache refer below url

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_speling.html

Also a similar question has been answered adding links to it here.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1998156/case-insensitive-urls-with-mod-rewrite